# Construir array multidimensional desde dos tablas o más en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, array, sql

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Tengo una duda sobre MySQL y PHP. Ojalá me puedan orientar.

¿Cómo se hace para obtener de MySQL el resultado de dos o más tablas cuando los resultados de la segunda son mayores a 1?

Por ejemplo, si quiero obtener todos los campos de usuario y a la vez de otra tabla todas las imágenes que el usuario haya registrado y a su ves todos los productos que haya adquirido.

Claro, teniendo en cuenta que están relacionadas por el ID del usuario.

La idea es que al recibir los datos se pueda asociar a un array multidimensional de forma sencilla sin tener que realizar primero la consulta del usuario, luego consultar las imágenes y posteriormente una tercer consulta . Lógicamente ya teniendo el ID del usuario.

Ejemplo:

```
array(
0 => array(
id_user => 1
imagenes => array(image1, image2, image3),
compras => array(
array(
id_compra => 1
),
array(
id_compra => 2
),
array(
id_compra => 3
)
)
)
)
```

Comprendo que hay que usar algún tipo de Join. Pero no me es posible imaginar el método de construcción del array.

ejemplo:

```
select id_user from usuarios;
Luego: select * from imagenes where id_user = $id_user;
Luego: select * from compras where id_user = $id_user;
```

Pero eso se podría resumir en:

```
select id_user, i.*, c.* from usuarios u inner join imagenes on u.id_user = u.id_user inner join compras c where c.id_user = u.id_user;
```

Pero luego de obtener estos datos, como se construiría?.

Ojalá alguien pueda asesorarme.
Tengan una excelente tarde. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitaria conocer tu diagrama entidad relacion para darte la consulta exacta, sin embargo la consulta deberia quedar algoa si:

```
SELECT usuario.idUsuario,imagenes.idImagen,compras.idCompras 
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN imagenes ON usuario.idUsuario = imagenes.idUsuario
INNER JOIN compras ON usuario.idUsuario = compras.idUsuario
WHERE usuario.idUsuario = ?;
```

Esa seria la consulta, ahora solo hay que vaciarla a PHP haciendo queries preparadas quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = " SELECT usuario.idUsuario,imagenes.idImagen,compras.idCompras FROM usuario INNER JOIN imagenes ON usuario.idUsuario = imagenes.idUsuario INNER JOIN compras ON usuario.idUsuario = compras.idUsuario WHERE usuario.idUsuario = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$idUsuario);
$stmt->execute();
$data = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $usuario = $row["idUsuario"];
    $imagen = $row["idImagen"];
    $compra = $row["idCompra"];
    $data[$usuario]["imagen"][]=$imagen
    $data[$usuario]["compra"][]=$compra;
}
$stmt->close();
```

Me parece que algo asi es como lo que estas buscando.
Ya partiendo de aqui puedes determinar que no se repitan datos y de mas.

Comment: Justo así lo imagino. Entonces, si tabla `compras` tiene más resultados que tabla `imagenes`, entonces me va a arrojar los resultados totales de la tabla con mayor resultado?. Qué pasaría con los valores de la tabla`usuarios` y `compras`? Quedarían en NULL?

Comment: No, el problema de hacer `INNER JOIN` es que te va a hacer un producto cruzado, me parece que para eso que tu dices se puede hacer con `UNION ALL` ahi si necesitaria ver tu ERR para determinar cual es la consulta correcta, puedes jugar con `LEFT/RIGTH JOIN` y determinar cual es la mas optima aunque segun tengo entendido mi respuesta de arriba podria funcionar.

Comment: Apenas comienzo a hacer la estructura de la base de datos. Pero al mismo tiempo intento visualizar como será el trato con los datos que se obtienen de todos los casos. El ejemplo que formulé es en una hipótesis de tener que relacionar dos o más tablas y que dos de ellas tengan valores superiores a 1. Realmente cualquier recomendación y/o ejemplo sería bien recibido para construir algo que funcione bien y sin complicaciones a futuro.

Comment: Pues en ese caso te recomiendo que lo vayas haciendo con POO, ademas de usar queries preparadas, esto para darle mas seguridad a tu sistema y en cuanto a tu consulta de compras e imagenes no me veo mucho sentido ya que parecerian estar separadas las tablas, sin embargo si tu compra fuera la que tuviera la imagen seria mucho mas sencillo, igual si requieres mas ayuda con gusto se te dara.

Comment: Entiendo lo del POO y preparar las consultas. Lo de imágenes y compras es un ejemplo burdo, puede ser cualquier otra cosa.
Agradezco mucho tu tiempo y atención. Me ayudaste bastante.

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos.